# Navigation Bar Troubles

Tags: css, html

I'm using a navigation bar for a project I'm working on. I've always had trouble with horizontal navigation bars, and I've looked everywhere for the right solution, without success. The navigation bar was shifted to the left, so I put in some padding in my css, and now it's centered, however the text is not centered in it, and the hover effect for the first link doesn't cover the whole 'box' the text is in.

CSS:

```
/* Entire Document CSS */
html{
    height: 100%;
}
/* Header CSS */
.headers{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #63B8FF;
}
.headers2{
    color: #FFD89A;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* Body CSS */
.body{
    background-color: #61B329;
    height: 50%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.container{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    height: 50%;
}
/* Navigation CSS */
.nav{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #00B2EE;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.nav li{
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 110px 10px 0.80px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Footer CSS */
#footer {
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 3em;
 margin-top: -3em;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}
/* Link CSS */
a:link{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    background-color: #028482;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: overline;
}
a:active{
    background-color: #FF9C00;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.Links A:hover{
    color: #028482;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline overline;
}
```

HTML5 (Index Page)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Play - Learn - Grow</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body class="body">

        <h1 class="headers">Welcome to KUBE Toy Library!</h1>

        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="membership.html">Become a Member</a></li>
                <li><a href="borrow.html">Borrow Toys</a></li>
                <li><a href="policies.html">Our Policies</a></li>
                <li><a href="sitemap.html">Site Map</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <h2 class="headers2">Welcome to the Home Page!</h2>

        <div class="container">

            Our aim is to provide the children of the community with an ever-changing variety of educational and fun toys to enhance
            their cognitive, social, emotional and physical development in the important first six years of their lives.

            <br><br><span class="Links">Be sure to check out our Wikispace site with more information <a href="http://mysocialmediatools-pn.wikispaces.com/">here</a>!</span>

        </div>

        <div id="content"></div>

        <div id="footer">
            Copyright &copy 2013
        </div>


      </body>

</html>
```

Note that I'm quite new compared to the others here on this forum, so please take it easy on me! :) Also this is a fictional company, etc. for an assignment I was given. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi your page in my browser was displayed like below
[image]

I changed your css to make it browser resolution independent. As a UI developer I felt that overline was not looking good so I removed that. Use my code

```
/* Body CSS */
.body {
    background-color: #61B329;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Header CSS */
.headers {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #63B8FF;
}

.headers2 {
    color: #FFD89A;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
}

/* Navigation CSS */
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #00B2EE;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 14.28%;
    float: left;
}

.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Footer CSS */
#footer {
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 3em;
 margin-top: -3em;
}

#content {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}

/* Link CSS */
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #028482;
}

a:active {
    background-color: #FF9C00;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.Links A:hover {
    color: #028482;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline overline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I made some changes while you answered this, and it works great! I took parts of the code you edited and it seems to work quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/NphBK/

This is a common problem. But to fix this you need to make the parent `text-align: center` and give the children `display: inline-block;`

If you want to have it completely equalizing you'll need to switch to `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful input! Much appreciated!